# Plural Form of Mongoose

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the Plural form of Mongoose?  I guessed that it should be mongeese, but is sounds funny. Mongooses also sounds funny.So *what is it*?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please include your the research you've done for this. You should come to EL&U only after commonly available resources have failed you.

Comment: Most dictionaries will tell you it is *mongooses*.

Comment: For the same reason plural Moose are not Meese.  Etymology: _Marathi maṅgūs_ whereas _goose/geese_ are from Old English

Comment: If you’re Jamaican, surely _mengeese_ would be the ideal plural, [mon](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mon).

Answer (score 2):

Plural form is *mongooses*. If you check in any other dictionary apart from this one I included in my answer, you would find the same plural form.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mongoose